# Instantiating multiple instances of a class from within

Tags: java, enums

Can someone explain how the below code works without any exceptions. I am thinking when new instance is created for SUNDAY it creates a new instance for MONDAY (inside SUNDAY) too and then SUNDAY again (inside MONDAY) and so on... Something like recursive as they both are part of the class Week. But my understanding is wrong because the below code is working fine.

```
public class Week {
    public static final Week SUNDAY = new Week("SUNDAY",0);
    public static final Week MONDAY = new Week("MONDAY",1);

    private String name;
    private int val;

    private Week(String name, int val) {
        this.name = name;
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return this.val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

I got this doubt when I was reading about java enums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see the mentioned behavior when `SUNDAY` and `MONDAY` are instance variables (non-static).

Since you have declared them as static those are the properties of the class and initialized when the `Week` class is loaded one after another. One object creation `SUNDAY` would not contain `MONDAY` in it and vice versa.

As I mentioned in the beginning, the below code won't run successfully as it will try to create instances recursively without an end.

```
public class Week {

    public final Week SUNDAY = new Week("SUNDAY",0);
    public final Week MONDAY = new Week("MONDAY",1);

    private String name;
    private int val;

    private Week(String name, int val) {
        this.name = name;
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return this.val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Week("TUESDAY", 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Week.SUNDAY.MONDAY)`  is working fine because class variables can be accessed either by ClassName.staticVariable or classInstance.staticVariable ?

Comment: Yes, when declared as `static`, these `class` variables can be accessed as `Class.variable` or `instance.variable` (no difference). However, you should access `static` variables as `Class.variable`.

Comment: Understood Thank You :)

Answer (score 2):

`SUNDAY` and `MONDAY` are `static` variables. Which means that they are class variables. Object of class `Week` will not have properties called `SUNDAY` and `MONDAY`

You can get more information regarding `static` here: [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)